# How do I pass in an authorization header with the pdf url in react-pdf-highlighter?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use [react-pdf-highlighter](https://github.com/agentcooper/react-pdf-highlighter) for highlighting certain fields on a pdf that were read by an OCR program. The current pdf view uses [react-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) which allows me to pass in an authorization header along with the url for the pdf. I'm not seeing the same option in the react-pdf-highlighter project, even though they both use [Mozilla's PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). Anyone know if there is a way to add headers for the pdf to be shown in react-pdf-highlighter?